# Can't see CVEs (vulnerabilities) on Sonar UI under Project>Issues. Used to see them in the past. Has anything changed?

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, owasp-dependency-check

We're using a combination of Jenkins and Sonar Plugin of OWASP DependencyCheck https://owasp.org/www-project-dependency-check/. The reports in HTML and JSON getting generated during pipeline build in Jenkins and also could see html reports from Project>More>Dependency Check in Sonar, but the vulnerabilities (CVEss) are no longer listed under Project>Issues>Security Category>OWASP Top 10 in Sonar. We were able to see the CVEs there in the past.

Has anything been changed?

We were able to see them before like shown in the screenshot below

[image]

Version of dependency-check used

```
Jenkins Dependency Check plugin: 5.4.0
Sonar Dependency check plugin: 3.0.1
```

I read about this https://sonarsource.atlassian.net/browse/SONAR-11970 but not sure if that's the reason behind now showing up CVEs under OWASP Top 10 category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue, there was a compatibility issue with the dependency-check version I was using in Jenkins. Downgrading the dependency-check version fixed the issue.